# In which Voyager episode did the Doctor have sexual relations?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, episode-identification, star-trek-emh

In the *Star Trek Voyager* episode "Message in a Bottle" (which is the 14th episode of the fourth season), the following dialogue takes place:

> The Doctor: I'm as close to a sentient life-form as any hologram could hope to be. I socialize with the crew, fraternize with aliens. I've even had sexual relations.
>
> EMH #2: Sex? How's that possible? We're not equipped...
>
> The Doctor: Let's just say, I made an addition to my program.
>
> EMH #2: Before you leave, maybe you could download those subroutines into my database.
>
> The Doctor: We'll see.

What prior episode is this an allusion to? The only episode I can recall which may have involved the Doctor having sex is "Lifesigns", where he falls in love with Denara Pel. However I don't recall any explicit or implicit references to sex in that episode.

Comment: The holodeck can make more than a simple opera house or a bar in France.

Comment: Could it be ["Real Life"](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Real_Life_(episode))? I haven't seen that episode in years so I can't confirm, but he did have a wife in that episode, albeit a holographic one.

Comment: Blink of an Eye -- EMH: Find out what happened to a boy named Jason Tabreez. He lived in the Central Protectorate. 
GOTANA-RETZ: Jason? An unusual name. 
EMH: Yes. He was my son. 
GOTANA-RETZ: But you're a hologram. 
EMH: It's a long story. He's dead by now, but perhaps you could discover what happened to him. Maybe he had children or grandchildren. You could tell them about me.

Comment: but Blink of an Eye  is not a prior one i guess

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the memory alpha article on [Voy: Lifesigns](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Lifesigns_(episode))

> It was intended by the writers (at least by the time of Voyager's fourth season) that – in the Mars holodeck program, shortly after they kiss – The Doctor and Denara Pel would have an unseen sexual experience together, an encounter that constituted the first time that The Doctor has sexual relations. (Cinefantastique, Vol. 30, No. 9/10, p. 85)